# Java command line arguments. Using * as an argument for multiplication

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run a java calculator application from command line. the parameters are as follows : operator operand1 operand2. I can successfully run the java program for + and - . 
e.g. 
java calc + 2 4 
java calc - 10 4

But when I try to run 
java * 2 5

`System.out.println(args[0]);` 
`System.out.println(args[1]);` 
`System.out.println(args[2]);`

gives output: 
.classpath 
.project 
.settings

I found out by trial and error that using single quotes( '*' ) solved my problem.
SO i have two questions now. 
1. Is using single quotes the right way to do it? (java calc '*' 2 5 ) 
2. What is the meaning of * in the java command line? (I've tried to find this on internet but didn't find much help)

Thanks,
Punit

Comment: Search the web for "filename expansion".  And yes, single quote the asterisks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not Java, it's the shell (`cmd` if you're on Windows) you are using that interprets `*` as "all files and folders in the current directory".

So when your write:

```
java calc * 2 5
```

You will actually give your program the following arguments:

```
java calc file_1 file_2 ... file_n 2 5
```

Where `file_1 ... file_n` are all files (and folders) in the current directory).

*If you do not want your shell to interpret `*` as all files you need (as you have noticed) to quote that argument.*

Comment: it should be " (double quoute) not ' (single quote).

Comment: @reader_1000: Good point as this was a "windows-only" question! (Other shells need other characters to quote or escape it.. For instance `sh` uses `\*`.)

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning which OS i was using. I'm using windows. And in windows cmd using double quote ( " ) still gives me the same error. Using single quote( ' ) though works fine. And as @dacwe rightly pointed out the escape sequence is different for different platforms. Thanks guys for the answer and comments :)

Answer (score 1):

If you quote your command arguments, the shell will not expand them to filenames. '*' has no special meaning to java it is the shell that processes this input.