# '*' as parameter changes to ".classpath, .project, .settings, bin, src,"

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, multiplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java command line arguments. Using * as an argument for multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441112/java-command-line-arguments-using-as-an-argument-for-multiplication)

i just wanted to write a simple calculator. 
If i enter 2 * 3 as parameters the array will look like this afterwards:

*[2, .classpath, .project, .settings, bin, src, 3]*

This happens for all our Eclipse installs in the company "Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857"

A friend of mine doesnt have this problem, so does anyone know the root of this problem?

greetings

Nico

Comment: Looks like the command shell (like bash) expands your arguments to file names. That would be a problem outside of your code or Java. How are you running your program?

Comment: Thats true, i didnt find that post i am very sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `*` gets replaced by the shell interpreter with the list of files in the current working directory. This typically happens on Linux/Unix platforms, but not (necessarily) on Windows. Does your friend use a Windows machine?

In other words, this has nothing to do with Java, but with the shell command interpreter which interprets your command line prior to executing `java`. To avoid it, you need to single-quote sensitive parameters, like `java MyApp 2 '*' 3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and helpful answer. He is using mac os and we are using Windows 7 in the company.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the parameters on the command-line, where '*' is actually the wildcard character; it will match all files in the current directory (which happen to be .classpath, .project, .settings, bin, src.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running under Unix, this is natural consequence of command-line expansion. Use `\*`, or `"*"`. If you're on Windows, it doesn't happen.